# Función que retorne un objeto con propiedades en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear una función que me retorne un objeto el cual tenga como propiedades las comidas y la cantidad de veces que se pidió esa comida.

Es decir, mi respuesta tiene que ser `{ standar:2 , vegan:1 }`.

Tengo este código:

```
pedirComida(
    [
        {
            nombre: "Harry",
            dieta: "standard"
        },
        {
            nombre: "Luna",
            dieta: 'vegan'
        },
        {
            nombre: "Goyle",
            dieta: "standard"
        }
    ] 
)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando. Agrega lo que has intentado.

Comment: function pedirComida(array) {
    // tu código acá
    var objeto={
        standar:0,
        vegan:0
    }
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 if(array[i].dieta==="standar") objeto.standar+= 1
 else if (array[i].dieta==="vegan") objeto.vegan+=1
    }
    return objeto

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta añadiendo lo que has intentado, describiendo el problema que tienes. Intenta ser lo más clara posible

Comment: Ok, entendemos lo que necesitas, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?...

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que intentar desarollar el código tu y si te encuentras con un problema específico -> preguntar aquí.

De todas formas, lo que necesitas es muy facil de lograr. Te lo explico esquemáticamente para que sepas por donde empezar.

Declara cada uno de los contadores de dieta inicializándolos a 0

```
var standard = 0;
var vegan = 0;
```

Ahora solo neceistas ir verificando, para cada usuario que dieta ha seleccionado. Para ello se utilizan los bucles (loops). Hay muchas maneras de hacerlos (while, for, forEach, map...). Para el caso que ncesitas lo más sencillo puede ser un `for`.

La estructura de un [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) es simple:

```
let desde = 0
let hasta = 10
for (let i = desde; i < hasta; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    // Pintara por pantalla 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    // Por que se repetirá solo mientras `i < 10`
}
```

Osea que en tu caso necesitas un for que te recorra todo el array, osea que recorda desde 0 hasta la longitud de tu array.

Aunque sepas que ahora es 3 (la longitud de tu array).. no pongas un 3 directamente, por que si luego son 4, no funcionará bien.

Para eso existe la popiedad [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) de los array que te cuenta las posiciones

Así que:

```
// Dado tu array: 
let tuArray = [
{ nombre: "Harry", dieta: "standard" },
{ nombre: "Luna", dieta: 'vegan' },
{ nombre: "Goyle", dieta: "standard" } ]

// Puedes saber su longitud así

let posicionesArray = tuArray.length // te dará un 3

// No olvide que te si te dá un 3 como length,
// significa que las posiciones existentes son: [0], [1] i [2] 
// En ningún caso existe la posicion tuArray[3]
```

Dicho esto ahora ya puedes recorrer todas las posiciones de tu array con el bucle `for` correctamente

```
var standard = 0;
var vegan = 0; 
let desde = 0
let hasta = tuArray.length
for (let i = desde; i < hasta; i++) {
    // aquí puedes hacer esto
    console.log(tuArray[i].nombre)
    console.log(tuArray[i].dieta)

    // Comprueba lo que pinta por consola,
    // y veras que solo te falta validar y sumar contadores
    //  Con un simple if lo tienes: 

    if (tuArray[i].dieta === 'standard' { 
        standard = standard + 1
    } else {
        vegan = vegan + 1
    }
    
    // O lo que sería lo mismo pero más elegante:

    standard = standard + tuArray[i] === 'standard' ? 1 : 0
    vegan = vegan + tuArray[i] === 'vegan' ? 1 : 0
    
}
```

Cuando todo esto te ha funcionado bien, preparar la salida de tu funcion es facil, ¿ quieres un objeto como salida ? Pues generas el objeto a tu gusto:

```
// standard y vegan son los contadores
return { 'standard': standard, 'vegan': vegan }

// O lo que es lo mismo:
return { standard: standard, vegan: vegan }

// O lo que es lo mismo:
return { standard, vegan }
```

Espero que te sirva, y recuerda que si simplemente copias y pegas... no vas a entender como funciona **esto de la programación**.